# Time complexity of finding 3 smallest elements in less than O(n) comparisons

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

I've 2 problems regarding determination of time complexity of 2 algorithms.

#### Problem 1

Determining the smallest 3 numbers from a set of *n* **distinct** numbers using comparisons.

1. These 3 elements can be determined using **O(log<sup>2</sup>n)** comparisons.
2. **O(log<sup>2</sup>n)** don't suffice, however they can be determined using **n + O(1)** comparisons.
3. **n + O(1)** don't suffice, however they can be determined using **n + O(logn)** comparisons.
4. **n + O(logn)** don't suffice, however they can be determined using **O(n)** comparisons.
5. None of the above.

> Here, the way I thought of it is to take 3 variables (e.g: MIN<sub>1</sub>, MIN<sub>2</sub> & MIN<sub>3</sub> where MIN<sub>1</sub> being the smallest & MIN<sub>3</sub> being the largest of these 3), initialize them with the 1<sup>st</sup> 3 elements of the list and scan the list once. For each number x in the list we have the following 4 cases:
>
> 1. **if** x < Min<sub>1</sub> **then**, Min<sub>3</sub> = Min<sub>2</sub>; Min<sub>2</sub> =  Min<sub>1</sub>; Min<sub>1</sub> = x;
> 2. **else if** Min<sub>1</sub> < x < Min<sub>2</sub> **then**, Min<sub>3</sub> = Min<sub>2</sub>; Min<sub>2</sub> = x;
> 3. **else if** Min<sub>2</sub> < x < Min<sub>3</sub> **then**, Min<sub>3</sub> = x;
> 4. **else if** Min<sub>3</sub> < x **then**, *do nothing*
>
> So, basically it'll require **3n comparisons in the worst case** and **0 comparison in the best case**.
>
> Correct me if it can be done in an otherwise easier (less time bound) way. Actually I'm confused with options **3** and **4**.

#### Problem 2

Determining both the smallest and the largest number from a set of *n* **distinct** numbers using comparisons.

1. these 2 elements can be determined using **O(log<sup>100</sup>n)**  comparisons.
2. **O(log<sup>100</sup>n)** don't suffice, however they can be determined using **n + O(logn)** comparisons.
3. **n + O(logn)** don't suffice, however they can be determined using **3.⌈<sup>n</sup>⁄<sub>2</sub>⌉** comparisons.
4. **3.⌈<sup>n</sup>⁄<sub>2</sub>⌉** don't suffice, however they can be determined using **2.(n-1)** comparisons.
5. None of the above.

> Using analogous argument as before I've come up with the answer **2(n-1)**. Although I'm still confused between options **2** and **4**.

Comment: How can one get the smallest element even without going through all elements at least once?

Comment: For problem 2, if option 2 is a candidate, then of course option 3 is too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem 1:
You can improve upon your algorithm to 2n comparisons by first comparing to MIN2. This is still O(n).
To see that n+O(1) doesn't suffice, note that there are n*(n-1)*(n-2) possibilities, where MIN1, MIN2, and MIN3 are located.
Take logarithm to base 2 to get the lower bound on the number of required comparisons.

Problem 2:
This can be done in 3*ceil(n/2) by comparing two successive elements, then comparing the smaller to the current min and the greater to the current max.